# How to return DB data efficiently

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass a big chunk of data via ajax call from the server.

I have

```
foreach ($results as $field){

    $data[]=$fieldName=array('ID'=> $field['ID'], 'Text'=> $field['Text']...and so much more);

}
```

I need to show the field name (`ID`) and the data (`$field['ID'`]). Are there faster way to do this without adding so many more fields manually in my array?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could select only the fields you really do require in your query, e.g.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 ...
```

instead of

```
SELECT *
```

Then you can simply do

```
while($row = fetch_from_db($result)) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that equivalent to:

```
foreach ($results as $field){
    $data[] = $field;
}
```

If it's an AJAX request expecting JSON, then just encode the whole thing in one function call:

```
json_encode($results);
```